# Ember app cannot load json data from local file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ember.js

I have been following the ember quick start guide to create an app that displays some data (https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/getting-started/quick-start/) but instead of displaying just a javascript array with scientists names, I want to display the products from the following json.

I have placed the json file in the public folder.

It looks like:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "_id": "58ff60ffcd082f040072305a",
      "slug": "apple-tree-printed-linen-butterfly-bow-tie",
      "name": "Apple Tree Printed Linen Butterfly Bow Tie ",
      "description": "This fun 40 Colori Apple Tree Printed Linen Butterfly Bow Tie features a design of various apple trees built from tiny polka dots. The back of this bow tie features a polka dot print in complementing colours which when the bow tie is tied will pop out from behind making for a subtle yet unique detail. The playful design, stand out natural linen texture, and colourful combinations make this bow tie a perfect accessory for any outfit!\n",
      "standard_manufacturer": "58cbafc55491430300c422ff",
      "details": "Size: Untied (self-tie) bow tie with an easily adjustable neck strap from 13-3/4'' to 19'' (35 to 48 cm)\nHeight: 6 cm\nMaterial: Printed 100% linen\nCare: Dry clean\nMade in Italy",
      "sizes": [
        {
          "value": "Violet",
          "size": "57722c80c8595b0300a11e61",
          "_id": "58ff60ffcd082f0400723070",
          "marked_as_oos_at": null,
          "quantity": -1,
          "stock": true,
          "id": "58ff60ffcd082f0400723070"
        },
```

and so on.

My code for the model of the route for displaying the list is as follows

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        //return ['Marie Curie', 'Mae Jemison', 'Albert Hofmann'];
        return Ember.$.getJSON("/products.json");
    }
});
```

I have followed the tutorial exactly except for the

```
return Ember.$.getJSON("/products.json");
```

line in scientists.js. My data is not being displayed and the error i get in the ember inspector is

```
compiled.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
    at E (compiled.js:2)
    at Object.u (compiled.js:25)
    at compiled.js:25
E   @   compiled.js:2
u   @   compiled.js:25
(anonymous) @   compiled.js:25
```

I am very new with ember and fairly new with js. Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ember comes with Development server(localhost:4200) and it can't be used like a webserver and it can't be used to response ajax request. You can't make this work `Ember.$.getJSON("/products.json")` with localhost:4200 endpoint.

You need backend any webserver to return response. If you don't have that at present then for development purpose, you need to work with dynamic render data, 
then I prefer to use [ember-cli-mirage](https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage) addon.

http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.3.x/

Answer (score 1):

What about placing the JSON in the app folder and importing it?

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import yourData from 'your-app/json-file-name.js';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return yourData;
  }
});
```

https://ember-twiddle.com/afb9d71933322860938b3936d617a776 - you can use this to try and get a .json working...

There is a thread here too: 
https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-import-data-from-json-file-to-ember-app

BUT... don't expect it to properly be in the ember-data store - and function like you'd expect in many situations.

Comment: All the 'story' data for this app I built was loaded from a static file in the app directory / so I know it's possible to work with something like this. http://judge.justicefor.us/

Comment: You'll likely have to reformat the JSON to be Ember-friendly

Comment: Did you mean for line 2: 
import yourData from 'your-app/json-file-name.json'

Comment: @yiannis - In my case, I put the "JSON-like" data in a standard JS file. Good point. I haven't tried it with a standard JSON file.