# Ember.js: this.store.push inside a forEach

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Hello I am trying to get some data in store at the startup of my ember app.

The following is in my routes/application.js file:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    var prods = Ember.$.ajax({url: ("/products.json"), type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', success: function(e) {
    var a = 1;
    e.products.forEach(function(f) {
        console.log(typeof(f.name));
        console.log(f._id);
        this.store.push({
            data: [{
                      id: a,
                      type: 'product',
                      attributes: {
                        name: f.name
                     }
                  }
               ]
            });
        a = a + 1;
        });
    }})
  }
});
```

I basically try to load some json data from locally, placed in the public folder of the app. Inside app/models/product.js my model looks like this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Finally my data looks like:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "_id": "58ff60ffcd082f040072305a",
      "slug": "apple-tree-printed-linen-butterfly-bow-tie",
      "name": "Apple Tree Printed Linen Butterfly Bow Tie ",
      "description": "This fun 40 Colori Apple Tree Printed Linen Butterfly Bow Tie features a design of various apple trees built from tiny polka dots. The back of this bow tie features a polka dot print in complementing colours which when the bow tie is tied will pop out from behind making for a subtle yet unique detail. The playful design, stand out natural linen texture, and colourful combinations make this bow tie a perfect accessory for any outfit!\n",
      "standard_manufacturer": "58cbafc55491430300c422ff",
      "details": "Size: Untied (self-tie) bow tie with an easily adjustable neck strap from 13-3/4'' to 19'' (35 to 48 cm)\nHeight: 6 cm\nMaterial: Printed 100% linen\nCare: Dry clean\nMade in Italy",
```

and so on.

When it is time to push in the store i get the following error:

```
application.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of undefined
at application.js:32
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Object.success (application.js:29)
at fire (jquery.js:3317)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3447)
at done (jquery.js:9272)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:9514)
```

Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you solve your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44987848/ember-app-cannot-load-json-data-from-local-file) Are you sure that you are getting a response in the success callback. if that's the case then to fix your error, you need local variable `this` and use it inside. like `let _this=this` and instead of `this.store` you need to say `_this.store`.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewLi, works perfectly

Comment: @kumkanillam I am sure i get a response object, with andrew's edit I managed to get to push all my data from the response in the store. The error in my previous question is still there but has not affected development yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could use arrow functions (=>) ES 6 syntax as **this** is lexical scoped always to solve the ambiguity.

> e.products.forEach((f)=> { this.store.push()... })